# How to solve "Gradle JAVA_HOME is set to an invalid directory," and how to set up the Gradle workspace right in IntelliJ?

Tags: java, gradle, intellij-idea, minecraft-forge

I've seen similar questions to this, but none of the methods worked while some of them weren't applicable. I'm running Gradle 3.0 with JDK 1.8 provided by IntelliJ. When I go to the directory of my mod folder on cmd and run `gradlew getIntellijRuns` it prompts me with this error:

> ERROR: JAVA_HOME is set to an invalid directory: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-15.0.1\jdk-15.0.1
> Please set the JAVA_HOME variable in your environment to match the location of your Java installation.

I have tried uninstalling every other jdk versions and then setting the path on this version of jdk, yet I still get prompted with this error. I don't see why it would appear as I'm using the jdk that IntelliJ provides to begin with. As I can't set up my workspace correctly, I cannot import essential libraries such as net.minecraftforge.*

I've also set my project to the `.main` version, tried to clean the cache to run `setupDecompWorkspace` on IntelliJ and I still can't get it right. I'll provide some images for clarity.

[Run/Debug Configurations](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kMC6U.png)

[JAVA_HOME Path](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XHZ4y.png)

[Import line](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aePWt.png)

[CMD prompt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AgTiC.png)

Comment: Reboot after changing `JAVA_HOME`, your `cmd.exe` session has cached the old invalid value `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-15.0.1\jdk-15.0.1` instead of `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-15.0.1`. For Gradle 3.0 set `JAVA_HOME` to JDK 8 location instead.

Comment: I was able to successfully set up the workspace, and JAVA_HOME is set right. However, I still can't seem to find GradleStart class or import the necessary libraries. ```Error: Could not find or load main class GradleStart.``` Thank you for all the help.

Comment: Share the [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Here is a pastebin link including the error log: https://pastebin.com/UAUnaWwM

Comment: Forbidden (#403)
Error, this is a private paste or is pending moderation. If this paste belongs to you, please login to Pastebin to view it.

Comment: I apologize for the inconvenience. The same error doesn't happen on this site: https://controlc.com/fdde5fb3 (Password: gradle)

Comment: Zip and share the project directory. The shared fragment is not enough to reproduce or understand the issue.

Comment: Here is a mediafire link to the folder: https://www.mediafire.com/file/w3d1b62uzhtulvo/MinecraftMods.zip/file  I also included the forge mod developer kit in case it helps with understanding the gradle. Thank you, although the file size turned out to be bigger than expected.

Comment: Your archive has 3GB of Java heap fumps: java_pid32924.hprof
java_pid51424.hprof
java_pid17240.hprof.

Comment: Should I be deleting those? I'm sorry! My understanding of the situation isn't too clear. Should I provide another archive after getting rid of them?

Comment: No need to, the project builds fine with JDK 1.8 from the command line. Did you set JAVA_HOME to JDK 1.8 installation directory instead of JDK 15? It will not work with the higher Java versions.

Comment: Right now JAVA_HOME is set to C:\Users\Name\.jdks\corretto-1.8.0_275 and the workspace was built correctly on cmd. For some reason, the main project still doesn't generate GradleStart and GradleStartServer nor does it import the libraries. Are they working for you?

Comment: Gradle project imports and builds in IntelliJ IDEA without errors: https://i.imgur.com/91Mm9f1.png.

Comment: I'll try to figure out what's wrong on my side. Thanks for helping me even though I'm a little inept!